# Table header JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is, how can I get text from header in javascript? So if I click on header I'll get alert with header text...

```
$("#myTable th").click(function() {
  alert(this.text());  //that doesn't work =)
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#myTable th").click(function() {
  alert($(this).text());  //use $(this)
});
```

`text()` is a jQuery method so you should apply it to a jQuery selector.
`this`, inside the function handler refers instead to the DOM node

Comment: Longer: `this` is a JavaScript object which lacks the `text()` method. `$(this)` converts it to a jQuery object which has that method.